# pandas boxplot for clustered boxes: how to set multilevel x axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

Friends,

Basically, I have the following pandas dataframe:

```html
Climate         Soil Crop irr
Temperate Pcg Cabbage 103.5
Temperate Pcg Cabbage 111.1
Temperate Pcg Cabbage 170.1
Temperate Pcg Cabbage 119.3
Temperate Scg Cabbage 123.8
Temperate Scg Cabbage 132.3
Temperate Scg Cabbage 191.9
Temperate Scg Cabbage 129.4
Temperate Zcg Cabbage 138
Temperate Zcg Cabbage 137
Temperate Zcg Cabbage 205.3
Temperate Zcg Cabbage 155.3
Continental Pcg Cabbage 129.6
Continental Pcg Cabbage 224.9
Continental Pcg Cabbage 259.7
Continental Pcg Cabbage 142.6
Continental Scg Cabbage 151.6
Continental Scg Cabbage 254.3
Continental Scg Cabbage 283.5
Continental Scg Cabbage 162.1
Continental Zcg Cabbage 158.1
Continental Zcg Cabbage 275.7
Continental Zcg Cabbage 290.8
Continental Zcg Cabbage 180.1
Subtropical Pcg Cabbage 441
Subtropical Pcg Cabbage 515.4
Subtropical Pcg Cabbage 554.6
Subtropical Pcg Cabbage 495.2
Subtropical Scg Cabbage 465.7
Subtropical Scg Cabbage 538.2
Subtropical Scg Cabbage 567.8
Subtropical Scg Cabbage 510.1
```

I want to plot the "irr" variable grouped by climate and soil type. Using the following piece of python code I managed to get what I wanted:

```html
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 7))
axes = axes.reshape(-1) # linearise axes 2d array for easy looping
for i, crp in enumerate(["Cabbage", "Green beans", "Potato", "Wheat"]):
    data=irrdata[irrdata.Crop==crp]                         
    data.boxplot(column='irr', by=['Climate','Soil'], ax=axes[i], grid=False) 

    
#    axes[i].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    
    axes[i].set_ylim([0, 600])
    axes[i].set_title("")   # no title for subplots

    # adjust location of plots titles
    axes[i].text(.85, .85, crp,
             horizontalalignment='center',
             transform=axes[i].transAxes)

# Irrigation requirements by soil type
fig.suptitle("")  # flush the old super titles
axes[0].set_ylabel("Mean irrigation requirement (mm)") # top LEFT
axes[2].set_ylabel("Mean irrigation requirement (mm)") # bot left
plt.tight_layout()
```

Well, almost because the result is not very satisfactory (please note I am only giving the data for the cabbage but the others are handled exactly the same way):

[image]

You could see how the X axis labels are overlapping. Also, I don't want to repeat the climate type for every soil type. Rather, i want to group the soil types per a climate class:

```html
Zcg Scg Pcg   Zcg Scg Pcg   Zcg Scg Pcg
 Temperate    Subtropical   Continental
```

And I want to climates and the soils to appear in the plot in the following order:

Temperate->Subtropical->Continental

Zcg->Scg->Pcg

I am using Pandas version 0.15.2

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn does this, including specifying a not-alphabetical order:

```
import seaborn as sns
cbg = pd.read_clipboard()
cbg.columns = ['Climate','Soil','Crop','irr']
sns.factorplot('Soil', x_order=['Zcg','Scg','Pcg'],
               col='Climate', col_order=['Temperate','Subtropical','Continental'], 
               row='Crop', y='irr', kind='box', data=cbg)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, this looks close but not exactly what I want. What I want is the same three plots above but in a single plot and instead of the label "Soil" you should have in as the second x label: Temperate (left), Subtropical (middle), Continental (right).